# CLion does not recognize project as C++14

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, c++14, clion

I have been working on a [personal project](https://github.com/JoaoBaptMG/ReboundTheGame) using CMake for some months. Previously, I was using a command-line centered approach (editing the code in an editor like Geany and then building using `make`), and thus I built my own `CMakeLists.txt` around my projects. My project has a root `CMakeLists.txt` that states the C++ standard used is C++14, with `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)` and `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)`, and adds the subprojects present in some subfolders.

Some time ago, I decided to try CLion, because of its various features. I imported the project into CLion (without letting it overwrite my `CMakeLists.txt`) and I am very satisfied with it until now. However, even though the newest versions of CLion state explicit support for C++14, the code analyzer still has problem with method type deductions (i.e. `auto` methods), which it deduces as `void`. My code anyway compiles fine and cleanly, because it uses my Clang installed toolchain.

My main `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

project(ReboundTheGame)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeModules ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install)
set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES ON)

set(COMMONS_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Commons)

if(MSVC)
    add_definitions(-D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /wd4244)
endif()

add_subdirectory(CppMunk)
add_subdirectory(ExportTools)
add_subdirectory(MainGame)
add_subdirectory(Languages)
add_subdirectory(Resources)

add_custom_target(install_everything
    "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" --build "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}" --target install
    DEPENDS MainGame Languages Resources
    COMMENT "Installing ${PROJECT_NAME}")
```

Interestingly enough, I created a blank C++14 from CLion to test its functionalities, and its `CMakeLists.txt` has the *exact same* command I used on my project's one:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(TestProject)    

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14) // what's the difference??

add_executable(TestProject main.cpp)
```

Yet CLion manages to correct infer the types of `auto` methods I use in the code.

So far, I have not delved into the `.idea` folders of both to discover what is wrong, but I am out of ideas now on how to solve this problem. I suppose this might be a mis-configuration of the project, so if anyone needs it, I can attach an archive of my stored folder for you to examine. I am using Ubuntu 17.10, set my `cc` to `clang` and my `c++` to `clang++`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CLion has problems with auto-type deduction. It could be IDE problem, not your code. 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CPP?q=%7Bauto%20and%20type%20and%20void%7D%20%23Unresolved

But we are working hard to make it better. Please, report your problem with code context if you did not find it in the list.